# How to update storage with objects

Tags: angular, ionic2

Hi I get to know how to use local storage in ionic2. every time when i set and get data i could easily get those objects, But now i need the previous data that are been stored in it.

```
// This form will have user name which is a string
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
logForm(form) {
    if (form.valid) {
        console.log(form.value);
        this.myData = form.value;
        this.setData();
    }
}
setData(){
    this.storage.set('userObj', JSON.stringify(this.myData));
    this.getData();
}
getData(){ 
    this.storage.get('userObj').then((data) => {
        console.log("get data", JSON.parse(data));

    });

}
```

When ever a new sting is been added to the 'userObj' it should get updated with a new set of string that user gives. could someone help me.

Comment: sorry, your question is not clear for me? do you need to replace the existing object with new one or what?

Comment: no i need to update the existing object with a new object

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// This form will have user name which is a string
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
logForm(form) {
    if (form.valid) {
        console.log(form.value);
        let dataExist: Array<any> = [];
        let storageData = this.storage.get('userObj').then((data) => {
          dataExist.push(JSON.parse(data));
        });
        dataExist.push(form.value)
        this.myData = dataExist;
        this.setData();
    }
}
setData(){
    this.storage.set('userObj', JSON.stringify(this.myData));
    this.getData();
}
getData(){ 
    this.storage.get('userObj').then((data) => {
      console.log("get data", JSON.parse(data));
    });

}
```

Comment: object gets over written, i need the new object as well as old object on calling getData() method @Pardeep Jain